# How do request a correct access token in ASP.NET Core for Azure AD to access Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I've an ASP.NET Core application using ASP.NET Core Identity and trying to authenticate against Azure AD.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("AzureAD", "Azure AD", option =>
    {
        option.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:AppId"]; 
        option.ClientSecret = "abc";
        option.Authority = string.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"]);
        option.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        option.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        option.SaveTokens = true;
        option.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        option.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,                       
        };
    });
```

Everything works fine, the user can login using its credentials.

Now i'm trying to access Microsoft Graph in order to receive the user's email address (it's not send as claim in the id_token).
But when I use the received access_token from the login flow the Graph aPI returns an error:

```
Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105
```

When I look at the access_token it looks weird. It's not a valid JWT.
`AQABAAAAAABHh4kmS_aKT5XrjzxRAtHzymKlkayx9UvCfyg_uHq1prmSP8f0Mi5BfiqkdIZeqJsBbm9SSbDbMrQ0JgNa6pa6M97IjVr6ZHdtt3ryT8vns_kz5BxkdJFkL79Ql3ywzyKldfLuX9jwq1eCgQ1MMdqKUDW4q5g38...`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` notification which could be used to acquire access token for microsoft graph api using ADAL/MSAL . Please refer to [this blog](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication) for ASP.NET Core 2.0 Azure AD Authentication .

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Now I've a "real" access token. Your code samples of your [GitHub repo](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth) also helped me. Especially getting a special access token for Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Please consider accept as answer which may help others who meet same problem .